# Word-wrap: break-word not working in <small> or any other element

Tags: html, css

So I have a code like this. But the `word-wrap` is not working. It works when I change it to div but I need `small`, or any other element. So any ideas why it's not working and not breaking the word?

```html
 <small style="width: 15px; word-wrap: break-word;">+{{$s->type }} {{$s->name}}</small>

<small style="width: 15px; word-wrap: break-word;">asfasfassaasfdffgdfgd</small>
```

www.ibb.co/mkaKrw this is how it looks in my project. So I want that words to break and go down. I dont need inline-block. So i want that, "Tılsımı" word to break. I'm not sure if the thing I want is possible but, I just wanted to ask css experts.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? small is not a block-element, try display:block

Comment: why keep the style within the element when you can have an external css file? That could be your issue. It's much easier to organize anyway. you don't even need to have another file. Just use the `<style>` element.

Comment: @RohanShetty while it's is true it's a good practise to have separate css-files, saying that could cause ops issue is blatantly wrong. Inline css works as well as css-files.

Comment: yeah.. @Esko i tried display:block, didnt work.. so silly like why its not working in elements which is not div.

Comment: In that case, why not add custom `<br>` where you need? Or is this for an unknown value? Could you make a picture or something of how you want it to look?

Comment: length of words are changing, so i need to make it break after exact limit, or width..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<small>` is an inline element by default, which won't take on any settings that refer to `block` elements, like `width`. So if you still want to keep it and have the `width` setting work, you have to convert it to a block or inline-block element by adding `display: block` or `display: inline-block`. I added background colors in the snippet below to make it more obvious.

```html
<small style="width: 15px; word-wrap: break-word;display:block;background:green;">+{{$s->type }} {{$s->name}}</small>

<small style="width: 15px; word-wrap: break-word;display:inline-block;background:yellow;">asfasfassaasfdffgdfgd</small>
```

Added after comments:

I suppose you have a situation like this:

```css
.container {
  width: 90px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.container small {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>This is a text that contains some <small>veeeeeeeeeeeerrrrrry</small> long words. This is a text that contains some <small>veeeeeeeeeeeerrrrrry</small> long words. This is a text that contains some <small>veeeeeeeeeeeerrrrrry</small> long words.</p>
</div>
```

Here the `width` applies to the container, not to `small`, `small` is only around the long words and contains the word-break property, so it's the only place where words can break:

Comment: yeah I got that what you mean but.. It becomes totally bad when I do like this, so maybe there is no answer to my question but thanks for your efforts to answer.

Comment: probably you just need to change the `width` setting in addition to making it a block - the `width` doesn't refer to the word width, but is the width of the container (in this case `small`).

Comment: Note that I added a second snippet + explanation to my answer.

Comment: well, it can be answer to some people but, in my case just its not helping me :( anyways thank you johannes, I think your answer can help some people.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the property "display:inline-block", see the snippet:

```html
 <small style="width: 15px; word-wrap: break-word; display:inline-block">+{{$s->type }} {{$s->name}}</small>

<small style="width: 15px; word-wrap: break-word; display:inline-block">asfasfassaasfdffgdfgd</small>
```

Comment: https://ibb.co/mkaKrw this is how it looks in my project. So I want that words to break and go down. I dont need inline-block. So i want that, "Tılsımı" word to break.. :(